# format_datetime not compatible with datetime_diff

Tags: kql

```
MyDatabase
| where SessionId == "ExampleSessionId" and Sensor_Name == "my_sensor"
| extend new_TimeStamp = format_datetime(TimeStamp,'yy-MM-dd [HH:mm:ss]')
| summarize Summarized_Numeric_Value = avg(NumericValue) by new_TimeStamp
| serialize 
| extend next_timestamp = next(new_TimeStamp, 1)
| extend time_diff_seconds = datetime_diff('second',todatetime(new_TimeStamp), todatetime(next_timestamp))
```

I've got the following database (MyDatabase) where I've got second to second data of (my_sensor) and each row contains a TimeStamp (containing milliseconds).

What I am trying to do is the following

- Remove the milliseconds from the timestamp and round to the nearest second
- Obtain the average of NumericValue for each timestamp where the millisecond has been eliminated
- Obtain the next TimeStamp
- Find out the difference in seconds from the current TimeStamp to the new TimeStamp

The issue is that, once I use format_datetime then kusto stops recognising my date as a date (so it doesn't work when I try to use datetime_diff, but then if I add todatetime to my datetime_diff function then the result is blank.

Basically my question is, how can I find the difference between 2 TimeStamps if I want to remove the milliseconds from my TimeStamps first?

Update: I tried to format the newTimeStamp as format_datetime(TimeStamp,'yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Remove the milliseconds from the timestamp and round to the nearest second*

you can use the ['bin()' function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction), for example:

```
print input = now()
| extend output = bin(input, 1s)
```

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-13 17:11:08.6566263 | 2023-03-13 17:11:08.0000000 |

```
print input = now()
| extend output = case(datetime_part("Millisecond", input) >= 500,
                       1s + bin(input, 1s),
                       bin(input, 1s))
```

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-13 17:10:01.9385958 | 2023-03-13 17:10:02.0000000 |